# Values in for loop not changing with incrementation?

Tags: c, for-loop

So, I have a simple C program which is supposed to output a decreasing number of spaces, and an increasing number of hashmarks in my new line. Here is the code I used to try to accomplished this:

```
for(x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    for(y = n - 1; y > 0; y--) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(int z = 2; z < n + 2; z++) {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

I expect, based on the code counting down like this, that I should see an output like:

```
   ##
  ###
```

However, when I run my code, I get a consistent output of:

```
   ###
   ###
```

Any thoughts on where I went wrong in my for loops that might have caused this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't your inner loops do something that depends on `x`? Otherwise, why would you expect them to output something different on each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
n = 3;
for(x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        printf("%c", (y < (n - x - 1)) ? ' ' : '#');
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Result:

```
  #
 ##
###
```

Answer (score 1):

Below a cleanest way of doing it.
2 loops:

- one for the space from `0` to `max MINUS row number`
- one for the hashtag from `0` to `max MINUS number of space`

Code:

```
int main() {
    int n =10;
    int x, y, z;
    for(x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y < n - x - 1; ++y) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(z = 0; z < n - y; ++z) {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will get as result:

```
         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########
```